# I want to load cifar10 dataset,but it have UnpicklingError: invalid load key, ''

Tags: python-3.x

```
import import pickle
import numpy as np
import os
import gzip
from sklearn.externals import joblib

datadir='E:/python/waa/cifar10/cifar-10-batches-bin'

def load_cifar_batch(filename):
with open(filename,'rb') as f :
    datadict=pickle.load(f,encoding='bytes')
    x=datadict[b'data']
    y=datadict[b'labels']
    x=x.reshape(10000,3,32,32).transpose(0,2,3,1).astype('float')
    y=np.array(y)
    return x,y

def load_cifar10(root):
    xs=[]
    ys=[]
    for b in range(1,6):
        f=os.path.join(datadir,'data_batch_%d.bin' % (b,))
        x,y=load_cifar_batch(f)
        xs.append(x)
        ys.append(y)
    Xtrain=np.concatenate(xs) #1
    Ytrain=np.concatenate(ys)
    del x ,y
    Xtest,Ytest=load_cifar_batch(os.path.join(root,'test_batch')) #2
    return Xtrain,Ytrain,Xtest,Ytest

x_train,y_train,x_test,y_test=load_cifar10(datadir)

print('training data shape:',x_train.shape)
print('training labels shape:',y_train.shape)
print('test data shape:',x_test.shape)
print('test labels shape:',y_test.shape)
```

if i changed from f=os.path.join(datadir,'data_batch_%d.bin' % (b,)) to f=os.path.join(datadir,'data_batch_%d' % (b,)),
it no .bin,the error is FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'E:/python/waa/cifar10/cifar-10-batches-bin\data_batch_1',How can I solve this issue, as I couldn't find a way to do that.help me please.

Comment: This is the kind of error you get when you attempt to unpickle a file that isn't actually in pickle format.  Perhaps it needs to be decompressed first, perhaps it's in a format that has absolutely nothing to do with pickle - it's impossible to tell with the information you've provided.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem might be with which data set you downloaded.

your programed worked just fine for me with Bin removed from file path

```
f=os.path.join(datadir,'data_batch_%d' % (b,))
```

Dataset chosen by me is CIFAR-10 python version

Download

```
Version     Size    md5sum

CIFAR-10 python version     163 MB  

CIFAR-10 Matlab version     175 MB  

CIFAR-10 binary version (suitable for C programs)   162 MB
```

Comment: Yes, you are right, I found that I am using a .bin database instead of a .py database